# Simplify jquery slideup loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, codepen

I am currently working on a text slider using jquery.

The code relies on slide toggle and fade working together.

The sample code is here https://codepen.io/fja3omega/pen/GwVYXM

My jQuery is:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery.fn.slideFadeToggle  = function(speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
    }; 
    var counted = 1;
    jQuery(".slidem").find( "#rotate1" ).slideFadeToggle();
    setInterval(function(){
        counted = counted + 1;
        torotate = "#rotate" + counted;
        if(counted!=5) {
            jQuery(".slidem").find( torotate ).slideFadeToggle();
        } else {
            counted = 1;
            jQuery(".slidem .rotater" ).show();
            jQuery(".slidem").find( "#rotate1" ).slideFadeToggle();
            jQuery(".slidem").find( "#rotate5" ).show();
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

I was wondering if there was a way to shorten or simplify the jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify and improve your code removing all the unnecessary `id` and `class` attributes. Also you might make your code more abstract to support any number of "slides" not only 5.

See the snippet below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
    return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
  };
  var n = 0, slides = jQuery('.slidem > div');
  (function slide() {
    n = n * (n < slides.length) || +!slides.show();
    slides.eq(n++).slideFadeToggle();
    setTimeout(slide, 1000);
  })()
});
```

```css
.irotate {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10% 0;
  display: block;
}

.thisis {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 20px;
}

.slidem {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="irotate">
  <div class="thisis">This is a&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="thisis slidem">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>simple</div>
    <div>super easy</div>
    <div>fun</div>
    <div>working</div>
  </div>
  <div class="thisis">&nbsp;Text Slider</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice.  Can you explain what the +!slides.show() does?  I have never used the "+!" expression before.

Comment: @fja3omega, Well, `slides.show()` returns `object` --> `!object` returns `false` --> `+false` returns `0`. So `n = n * (n < slides.length) || +!slides.show();` is a hacky way to say `if (n >= slides.length) {n = 0; slides.show();}`. I'd suggest you using a "standard" syntax, cuz "seniors" would mad at you otherwise =))

Comment: Thanks.  I did not know you could combine that.  Great shortcut.